# How to generate random numbers based on a 3d weighted array in R?

Tags: r, random

I have a `3d array`and each dimension contains 7 elements(Overall `7*7*7= 343` elements). Each element contains a number between `0` and `1` which is the **weight of that cell**:

```
pop = sample(1 : 100, 7 ** 3, replace = TRUE)
prob = array(pop / sum(pop), c(7,7,7))
```

Now, **I need to randomly select one cell of this array based on the weight of each elements**.

But, i don't know how to select a cell randomly.
I wish the proper response returns 3 different numbers between `1` to `7`.

For example, if it returns `2,4,3` then i figure out it is the cell with coordination of `2,4,3`

Comment: The array part of the question is a bit of a distraction. If you can select an element given a vector of length `n` then it is just some modular arithmetic to get the indices when you throw in dimensions

Comment: @JohnColeman Do you mean, i should first convert my `3d` array to `1d` and then get a random number between `1` and `343` and obtain 3 numbers from that number?

Comment: Maybe simply: `x <- sample(1:7, 3); prob[ x[1], x[2], x[3] ]` ?

Comment: @zx8754 i think, you are not considering the weight of cells when you generate numbers. Could you please write it as an answer, so i can get some feedback from the other people?

Comment: This is not clear to me, could you explain? `"I need to randomly select one cell of this array based on the weight of each elements."`

Comment: You can consider the array as a cube with `343` cells. Each cell has a chance to be selected. This chance is value of that cell. For instance, if `prob [1,4,6]==0.143` then the chance (or weight) of selecting `1,4,6` must be `0.143` @zx8754

Answer (score 4):

The following works:

```
arrayInd(sample(1:343,1,prob = prob),c(7,7,7))
```

`sample(1:343,1,prob = prob)` selects a number between 1:343 with the requisite probabilities, after which `arrayInd()` turns that number into a vector of indices.